# How to get dual monitors going with Windows Server 2008 SP2 x64?

Tags: 64-bit, multiple-monitors, windows-server-2008

Dual monitors won't work in Windows Server 2008 SP2 x64, got the latest BIOS and latest video drivers.

#### (GeForce 9400GT / Gigabyte GA-EP45-UD3P)

Any ideas?

#### more info: computer boots just fine, second monitor is not getting a signal. I can see the second monitor in Display Settings, but selecting it as a second monitor does nothing.

Comment: a more detailed explanation of "won't work" would help a bit. Does the computer not post? does the monitor simply not receive a signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much explanation given I can only assume as to what the problem is. DVI cords tend to die every once in a while, they have caused me a lot of headaches in the past. You may want to check that first, a replacement is fairly cheap.

Some other users of 64-bit Windows Operating Systems have noticed this problem with the 9400GT as well. [Apparently is has to do with Nvidia's drivers](http://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/21386-cant-add-second-monitor-geforce-9400gt.html).

Comment: My DVI cable is fine